# Move Volumes between Containers?

Tags: macos, apfs

So I installed the Mojave beta on a separate container from my High Sierra install, but I really meant to install it in a separate volume. So now I have two containers and my Mojave install has run out of space (It was only 20GB), so I'm trying to move the Mojave volume from Container2 (20GB) to Container1 (230GB), and then delete Container2 so Container1 has the full 250GB. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd guess Carbon Copy Cloner or equivalent. Wouldn't like to attempt it 'live' with no safety net.

Comment: Is there no equivalent to something like `zfs send`?

Comment: What does `diskutil apfs list` show? If you are lucky the copy has room enough to copy in place.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ULeWrCha

Comment: I should note, my mojave install is actually on disk0s3 and not on "mojave"

Comment: Try ```asr restore```.